# Why is one of these functions faster than the other, even though it should be the other way around?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a program to calculate all primes up to a specific number. I've been using a timer to optimize the function and I can calculate primes up to 20 million in less than 4 seconds. The problem is, one of the optimizations actually made the program slower, even though it's doing less stuff.

Old function (the faster one):

```
function getPrimesOld(max) {
    const arr = [1];
    function isPrime(i) {
        const s = Math.sqrt(i);
        for (const h of arr) {
            if (h === 1) continue;
            if (h > s) break;
            if (!(i % h)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    for (let i = 2 ; i < max ; i += 2) {
        if (isPrime(i)) arr.push(i);
        if (i === 2) i--;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

New function:

```
function getPrimes(max) {
    const arr = [2];
    function isPrime(i) {
        const s = Math.sqrt(i);
        for (const h of arr) {
            if (h > s) break;
            if (!(i % h)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    for (let i = 3 ; i < max ; i += 2) {
        if (isPrime(i)) arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I ran both functions 10 times and averaged the time it took them, here are the results:

```
New function: 3544ms,3188ms,3513ms,3510ms,3511ms,3512ms,3503ms,3515ms,3513ms,3509ms (avg: 3481.8ms)
Old function: 3368ms,3388ms,3363ms,3355ms,3359ms,3350ms,3354ms,3354ms,3353ms,3356ms (avg: 3360ms)
```

(Just to make it clear, running the old function 10 times first instead of the new one doesn't affect the results. Old always averages around 3.35s and new always averages around 3.5s)

Why is the old function faster than the new one?

Comment: Did you run them sequentially in the same run? micro-benchmarking is as much about the benchmarking code as the code you're testing.

Comment: Yes, I am running 1 function after the other, but the order doesn't seem to matter. I've tried running the functions asynchronously but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have an if statement which makes the index get 1 subtracted so that it runs back to the odd numbers. If I try to address this by just adding 2 into my array, instead of starting with 2 and subtracting and going back to odds, it just makes the program slower.

Comment: FWII, the times I got for the old approach are `3851.523193359375, 3917.2490234375, 4158.049072265625, 3921.333251953125, 4291.134765625, 3814.952880859375, 4292.243896484375, 3917.309814453125, 3924.98779296875, 3929.676025390625`. The times for the new approach: `3332.09619140625, 3352.46435546875, 3333.411865234375, 3342.1591796875, 3365.5458984375, 3337.2900390625, 3410.093994140625, 3339.74609375, 3324.110107421875, 3327.9267578125`. **Old avg: 4001.8459716796874**, **New avg: 3346.4844482421877**. It's possible you are just getting insignificant noise.

Comment: Just reran to see if it was a fluke: **Old avg: 3815 ms**, **New avg: 3400 ms**

Comment: [primes-generator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/primes-generator) can calculate primes up to 20,000,000 in under 60ms, in case you want to save yourself the pain ;) [See complete code example](https://gist.github.com/vitaly-t/280c6f925c1c2d7e55be609ee0fe938e).

Comment: If speed is the main priority, then caching would be the best approach. At least caching the first thousand or so. I'm assuming that there's an educational element to this question which preempts caching.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica Since the author is asking about calculating primes up to 20 millions, caching is beside the point.

Answer (score 1):

I got a little obsessed with this, I admit, but I'm not seeing the performance degradation you are talking about. While the difference is extremely small, your new approach does appear to be every so slightly faster (running *Chrome Version 94.0.4606.81 (Official Build) (x86_64)* on *macOS Big Sur 11.6 (20G165)*).

One sample result from the test below:

```
Old Results:
- Mean: 3744 ms
- Median: 3735 ms
New Results:
- Mean: 3350 ms
- Median: 3276 ms
```

I'd be curious to see what other readers discover:

```js
const debugElem = document.getElementById("debug");
debugElem.innerText = "Press Start to Begin";

function getPrimesOld(max) {
  const arr = [1];
  function isPrime(i) {
    const s = Math.sqrt(i);
    for (const h of arr) {
      if (h === 1) continue;
      if (h > s) break;
      if (!(i % h)) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  for (let i = 2 ; i < max ; i += 2) {
    if (isPrime(i)) arr.push(i);
    if (i === 2) i--;
  }
  return arr;
}

function getPrimes(max) {
  const arr = [2];
  function isPrime(i) {
    const s = Math.sqrt(i);
    for (const h of arr) {
      if (h > s) break;
      if (!(i % h)) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  for (let i = 3 ; i < max ; i += 2) {
    if (isPrime(i)) arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}

async function testPrimes(fn) {
  await logMsg(`Running test for ${/function \w+/.exec(fn+"")}`);
  const stats = {
    times: [],
  };
  async function runTest() {
    const start = performance.now();
    await fn(20000000);
    const end = performance.now();
    return end - start;
  }
  for (let i = 10; i--;) {
    const diff = await runTest();
    await logMsg(`${i}... ${Math.round(diff)} ms`);
    stats.times.push(diff);
  }
  stats.times = stats.times.sort();
  stats.avg = stats.times.reduce(
    (acc, d) => acc + d,
    0
  ) / stats.times.length;
  stats.mdn = (stats.times[4] + stats.times[5])/2;
  
  return stats;
}

function logMsg(msg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    debugElem.innerText += msg + "\n";
    // console.log(msg);
    // Due to JavaScript's single-threading, we need to introduce
    // a slight delay in order to update the UI. This only happens
    // AFTER a test has finished, so it won't affect the times
    // reported by the test
    setTimeout(resolve, 0);
  });
}

document.getElementById("start").onclick = (async function() {
  debugElem.innerText = "";
  const results = {};
  results.old = await testPrimes(getPrimesOld);
  debugElem.innerText = "";
  results.new = await testPrimes(getPrimes);
  debugElem.innerText = "";
  logMsg("Old Results:");
  logMsg(`- Mean: ${Math.round(results.old.avg)} ms`);
  logMsg(`- Median: ${Math.round(results.old.mdn)} ms`);
  logMsg("New Results:");
  logMsg(`- Mean: ${Math.round(results.new.avg)} ms`);
  logMsg(`- Median: ${Math.round(results.new.mdn)} ms`);
});
```

```css
#debug {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", monospace, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: I get "Old results: 5358 ms; New results: 5412 ms" so ever so slightly slower. Chrome 94 on Win10.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - gotta pay as much attention to the median as the average. A single slow loop will throw the average off by quite a lot, but the median is pretty resilient to outliers.

Comment: Mean and median were basically identical. I just ran it again and got Old: 6822/6823; New: 7302/7334, which is a bit strange that it's so much slower when I haven't changed anything...

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I run this test on my Windows partition, it tells me that the new function is slightly faster, but when I run it on my Ubuntu partition, it tells me that the old function is faster. Weird.